# Specs2 Matchers for Validated and ValidatedNel

Tags: scala, matcher, specs2, scala-cats

I did not find `specs2` matchers for `ValidatedNel` of `cats` so I am writing matchers like that:

```
import cats.data._
import cats.implicits._
import org.specs2.matcher.Matcher

type ValidationFailure = String

type ValidationResult[A] = ValidatedNel[ValidationFailure, A]

def beValid: Matcher[ValidationResult[_]] =
  beTrue ^^ ((_: ValidationResult[_]).isValid)

def beInvalid(failure: ValidationFailure): Matcher[ValidationResult[_]] =
  beEqualTo(failure.invalidNel)

def beInvalid[A: Monoid](failures: ValidationFailure*): Matcher[ValidationResult[A]] =
  beEqualTo(failures.toList foldMap (_.invalidNel[A]))
```

Does it make sense ? How would you suggest improve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think deriving matchers from other matchers is nice because it gives you some quick win. However the failure messages might not be great. For example the `beValid` matcher will fail by telling you that a value is not `true`. So I suggest to write something like:

```
def beValid: Matcher[ValidationResult[_]] = { actual: ValidationResult[_] =>
  (actual.isValid, s"$actual is not valid")  
}
```

Also a PR in the [specs2-cats](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/tree/master/cats/src) module would be greatly appreciated if you have the time :-).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will probably change my matchers. I will have a look at the `specs2-cats` module too.